In the book of Acts 8:34-39, did the Ethiopian Eunuch receive the Holy Spirit?
Much of what we see in the book of Acts is the transition between the OT & the NT.
The believing Samaritans (Acts 8:12), had not received the Holy Spirit, they had simply been baptised in the name of the Lord Jesus.For God's own reason, they had not yet been baptized in the Spirit. We know that the Spirit did come upon the Samaritans, but it was not until after Peter & John were present (Acts 8:14-17, and Peter & John placed their hands on them & they received the Holy Spirit.
Jesus had given Peter the "keys to the kingdom", (Matthew 16:19)  Peter was present the day of Pentecost, when the spirit was given to the Jews.  He was present in Samaria, when the spirit was given to the Samaritans, & Peter was present in Cornelius's house when the spirit was given to the Gentiles.  Jesus used Peter to "open the door" to each of these groups.
God made sure that Peter & John, Apostles & Jews from Jerusalem, were present to witness the gift of the Spirit given to the Samaritans. The Samaritans were part of the same church that had been started in Jerusalem, & they were filled with the same spirit (Galatians 3:28).  Peter & John were eyewitnesses.  God prevented the early church from immediately dividing into different sects.
At the time of the Eunuchs baptism, Peter & John were not present, so did he received the Holy Spirit?

No. See the answer at https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/81262/did-the-ethiopian-eunuch-receive-the-holy-spirit-when-philip-baptised-him/81362#81362.
